# Wazuh Agent not connecting

Tags: ossec, wazuh

I have two questions. My Immediate problem is WAZUH-AGENT never connects to WAZUH-MANAGER

A. That makes me think, While installing Wazuh Manager, where do we provide WAZUH MANAGER IP?

B. I registered Windows and RHEL machines as agents but none of them are able to connect - all agents are NEVER CONNECTED status.

From windows , it is the error . I am using port#1515 and TCP

> ERROR: (1216): Unable to connect to 'xx.xxx.105.75': 'A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.'

I even tried changing 1515 to 1519 from Kibana-Wazuh app. And added my Agent IP in white-list, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 8):

Answering your questions according to the current version of wazuh `v3.13.1` as of today:

*[A] While installing Wazuh Manager, where do we provide WAZUH MANAGER IP?*

In the installation of the manager you don't have to configure any IP unless you are configuring the cluster mode. `WAZUH MANAGER IP` **is necessary to configure it in the agents**.

After installing the agent, you have to:

- Add the manager's ip address in the configuration file `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf`

  ```
  <address>MANAGER_IP</address>
  ```
- Register the agent in the manager. The simplest method is

  ```
  /var/ossec/bin/agent-auth -m MANAGER_IP
  ```
- Restart the wazuh agent

  ```
  systemctl restart wazuh-agent
  ```

Once these steps are applied, you should have your agent connected and reporting to the manager.

---

*[B] I registered Windows and RHEL machines as agents but none of them are able to connect - all agents are NEVER CONNECTED status.*

After having performed the steps mentioned above, you should have connection of the agents with the manager. If not, then a troubleshooting process must be followed.

- Check that the agent has successfully registered in the manager. You can use the command `/var/ossec/bin/agent_control -l` and see if the manager has the agent registered.
- Check that you have a connection to the manager from the agents.
- Wazuh uses by default ports `1515/TCP` for registration and `1514/UDP` for communication. Check that you have a connection through these ports (check firewall rules ...)
- To avoid possible problems, check that your manager's version is `>=` that the agent's version.
- Check if there has been an error in `/var/ossec/logs/ossec.log` file.

I hope this information is helpful to you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

A.You will have to edit ossec.conf file and make sure you have the MANAGER_IP address put it right place.

B.After you complete the section A. and if 1514/1515 ports are opened, you will be seeing your agent on the manager. Do not forget to register your aget to the manager.

Answer (score 0):

I Think there have two steps:
1.To edit ossec.conf in agent. to change the 'MANAGER_IP' to real manager IP. This is very import and it's very easy to forget to edit it.
2.Restart the Agent.